# Why does chi square test seem to depend on sample size?

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size

This question relates to my [ENT anti-answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27001/what-values-constitute-failing-for-ent-tests/31410#31410) in another forum, but is based on a statistical perspective.

Traditionally, the chi test does not depend on how many samples you take, so it should be as good for a 100 as for 2 billion.  There is certainly no mention of a relationship in the Wiki article.  This seems counter intuitive.

If you look at my graph of the distribution of  numbers (0 -255) in  a random stream, the chi value drops (asymptotically?) to a zero value.  You would expect this in the limit, as the distribution of random bytes should be totally flat.  The implicit consequence is that any derived p value (passing /failing a hypothesis) cannot be relied upon without consideration of sample size.

Why is this curve asymptotic?  Clearly and typically, I'm confused.  Judging by the long list of Similar Questions on my right, so are many others. There must be some perceptual issue here...

Update:  This only (for me at least) seems to hold for random numbers generated by Java's SecureRandom.  All the other generators I use seem to have chi's unrelated to the sample size as the literature suggests.  I had thought that perhaps the chi distribution was based on the number of histogram bins being the square root of the number of overall samples.

Comment: Wild guess: doesn't the sample size determine the sample standard deviation? Could this be somehow related to the issue you mention?

Comment: @barrycarter So you're implying that chi-square values (and thus p values) directly depend on the sample size?  But this isn't in the literature...

Comment: The test statistic that you compute, i.e. $X^2 = \sum_{i,j}\frac{(o_{ij}-e_{ij})^2}{e_{ij}}$ has ''asymptotically'' a chi-square distribution.  So the larger your sample the closer the distribution of $X^2$ will be to chi-square.

Comment: I don't understand what the assertion in the first sentence of your second paragraph is intended to convey, but whatever it is you need to support the claim being made. If something is actually "traditional", can you show a  reference in the statistics literature that actually states whatever it is?

Comment: @Glen_b as in Ms Gustavsen's answer.  As you know, determining a p value from chi requires the chi squared value and the degrees of freedom.  There's no place to also include the number of samples used in calculating chi.  But my contradictory example suggests that there is a relationship...

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to see the connection at all. You said "Traditionally, the chi test does not depend on how many samples you take". This is a surprising thing to say since *of course* the chi-square test depends in several important ways on the sample size (e.g. try taking a larger sample and calculating the chi-square -- did you get exactly the same value?). I don't see anything in the answer that establishes any tradition as claimed. Rather than relying on saying there's some tradition (or the unclear connection to the present answer), better to explain what you mean in your question.

Comment: @Glen_b  Hmm. So you're saying that if I have a fair die, the more times I throw it and test for fairness, the smaller chi will become as the observed probability approaches the theoretical 1/6th?  After a google throws it will be zero?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't say that. No, the discrete distribution of the chi-square statistic will approach the (continuous) chi-square distribution more closely as you take larger sample sizes.

Comment: Good question. This seems to be related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317331/the-effect-of-sample-size-on-chi-square-test

Answer (score 2):

The chi square distribution that is used in the common chi square test is defined by the parameter "Degrees of freedom". The degrees of freedom is the number of values in the final calculation of a statistic that are free to vary. So for instance, if you already have used the data to calculate the mean, and you then use the same data to calculate the variance (with this mean as an input), then you have used one degree of freedom for the calculation of the mean, and the DF would be DF = num obs -1.

Comment: I was referring to the number of overall samples taken in order to derive chi, not the degrees of freedom.  My example ranges across 1 MB, 10MB, 100MB, 1GB and 2GB samples, and chi squared asymptotically falls.  Where would I enter 2 billion in to the calculation?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here, the degrees of freedom is calculated from the number samples taken. So to answer your question, you enter the 2 billion in the calculation of the degrees of freedom.

Comment: I believe the OP had in mind applications where results are classified into 256 predefined bins, not two billion of them.  The DF therefore would be constant at 255.  Unlike what is asserted in the question, though, the sampling distribution of the $\chi^2$ statistic would indeed approximate a $\chi^2(255)$ distribution with extreme accuracy at those huge sample sizes.  As @fcop noted in a comment to the question, the sample size plays a role in the calculation of $\chi^2$ (because the bin counts $e_{i}$ will be directly proportional to it).