# The effect of sample size on chi-square test

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have two categorical variables and I want to do the chi-squared test. I was wondering if the gap between the sample sizes in each cell will affect the results?

```
         normal    nonormal
test1   n=6000      n=6000
test2   n=2500      n=2500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As the number of observations increases, the power of the test increases. Intuitively, as we have more data, we can be more certain about our effect size not being attributable to noise.

In terms of the actual test, the null distribution (the chi-squared distribution with # of cells - 1 degrees of freedom) remains fixed across any sample size, but the [chi-squared test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Pearson.27s_chi-squared_test) will grow with the sample size.

Consider the following example from the wikipedia page, where the effect size (proportions between cells) remains fixed, but the sample size grows:

```
worker_data <- as.matrix(data.frame(white_collar = c(90,60,104,95,349),
                                    blue_collar = c(30,50,51,20,151),
                                    no_collar = c(30,40,45,35,150)))

chisq.test(worker_data)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  worker_data
X-squared = 24.571, df = 8, p-value = 0.001837

chisq.test(worker_data * 2)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  worker_data * 2
X-squared = 49.142, df = 8, p-value = 5.97e-08
```

Comment: Is it possible to compare P values coming from different chi-squared test of homogeneity, each of these with different sample sizes? Since the sample size affects significance, it sounds that comparison will not be independent of sample sizes.

Comment: @elcortegano I'm not sure what you mean by "compare" and in what setting you want to do this. As usual, a p-value from this test represents the probability of measuring an effect size as strong as observed, given no "true" effect exists. p-values can be treated just like any conditional probabilities; that the test statistic is dependent on sample size (at fixed effect size) does not change this.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread but I think I will provide an answer still.

Let's say I've got a bigger sample size and realized that the test statistic becomes too large to be comparable to the chi-square table. What I mean by that is that let's say your sample size is instead $10$, and so your test statistic ends up being around $1$. Since the chi-square value for your test is e.g. $5$, you will say that the differences observed do not warrant rejecting $H_0$.

But if you just copy the same sample (to pretend you have a bigger sample of the same variation) you will end up with for example a test statistic = $10$ for a sample size of $100$...and now suddenly you have rejected $H_0$, so its all a matter of sample size.

Even the smallest difference in two datasets can be argued to stem from an actual statistically significant difference if only we make the sample size big enough...that to me sounds like really bad science.

Comment: This does not seem to add much to the existing answer but it does contain a new question. I suggest deleting this one and asking a new question with a link back to here.